# Children count depends on method in test

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

While experimenting with a self-referencing ManyToOne entity I find the count of children depends on the method used to find the parent.  If the Repository is used, the test fails with `Failed asserting that 1 matches expected 2`.  If instead DQL is used the test succeeds. See `testTwoKids()` in test segment below.  I've confirmed in debug that the actual count in the database is 2 in both cases.

My guess is there's something wrong with the entity definition.

#### Entity:

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     **/
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children", cascade={"persist","remove"})
    *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $parent;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addChildren($child)
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add children
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $children
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addChild($child)
    {
        $this->children->add($child);
        $child->setParent($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove children
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $children
     */
    public function removeChild(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $children)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($children);
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }
}
```

### Test

```
class CategoryTest extends KernelTestCase
{

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
                ->get('doctrine')
                ->getManager()
        ;
        $product = new \AppBundle\Entity\Product();
        $product->setName('foo');
        $this->em->persist($product);

        $cat = new \AppBundle\Entity\Category();
        $cat->setName('Hook');

        $child = new \AppBundle\Entity\Category();
        $child->setName('Dry');
        $child->setParent($cat);
        $this->em->persist($child);

        $this->em->flush();
    }

    public function testTwoKids()
    {
        $c = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findOneBy(['name' => 'Hook']);
        $cat = new \AppBundle\Entity\Category();
        $cat->setName('Wet');
        $this->em->persist($cat);
        $c->addChild($cat);
        $this->em->persist($c);
        $this->em->flush();

        /* this returns 1 */
        $c2 = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findOneBy(['name' => 'Hook']);
        $children = $c2->getChildren();
        $this->assertEquals(2, count($children));

        /* this returns 2 */
//        $id = $c2->getId();
//        $children = $this->em->createQuery("SELECT c FROM AppBundle:Category c WHERE c.parent = $id")
//                ->getResult();
//       $this->assertEquals(2, count($children));

            }
```

Comment: I think you'll find it's a bug in your test. I can't quite follow what is going on, but it might be an issue with Doctrine result caching. There are two many factors involved there to isolate it to a problem with Doctrine. The entity definition looks fine. Although that `addChildren()` method is a bit odd. Try running `$this->em->clear();` after your last flush as well.

Comment: @Ryan Excellent! `$this->em->clear();` solves the problem.  Post as solution and I'll gladly accept. Btw, `addChildren()` is an artifact of using `doctrine:generate:entity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `$this->em->clear()` after your last flush as well. It may be caused by the Doctrine entity manager caching or result caching.